# Only When Inputs are Filled in Specific Order are Percents Calculated Correctly

Tags: javascript, object, math, replace, addeventlistener

Similar to a spreadsheet, certain "cells" are calculated from the inputs of others. The problem is that by filling cells in arbitrary order, the sums and percents calculate differently depending on that order.

- The numbers are stored in arrays stored in objects.
- There is a naming
  scheme such that object keys can be used to refer to the id's of
  `html` elements.
- `addEventListener` and `forEach` are used with
  `Object.keys` to add the listeners.
- `parseInt` and `toString` are used in
  tandem with the naming scheme for text replacement after calculation.
- `document.querySelector` is used throughout.
- There are sums and percents for each column and row as well as an overall sum and percent.

Each row and column has two declared objects associated with it with a third generated; The first is the source of all the keysNames & id's, the second stores the inputs in keys named from the first for calculation, the third is generated as the calculations run and stores the numbers for display.

**Problem function:**

```
const doCalculation = function(confidenceValue, keyName) {
    try {
      let totalSubtotal = Object.values(sumTable).reduce((a, b) => a+b, 0);
      let featureDivisor = parseInt(document.querySelector(`#${keyName}Max`).textContent);
      document.querySelector('#totalPoints').textContent = totalSubtotal.toString();
      document.querySelector('#overallPercent').textContent = Math.floor((totalSubtotal/300)*100).toString() + ' %';

      totalSumObj[keyName][confidenceValue] = parseFloat(document.querySelector(`#${confidenceValue}`).value);
      sumTable[keyName] = 0;
      sumTable[keyName] = Object.values(totalSumObj[keyName]).reduce((a,b)=>a+b, 0);
      //Object.keys(totalSumObj[keyName]).forEach((el) => { sumTable[keyName] += parseInt(totalSumObj[keyName][el], 10); });
      document.querySelector(`#${keyName}`).textContent = sumTable[keyName].toString();

      quotientTable[keyName] = 0;
      Object.values(sumTable).forEach((el) => { quotientTable[keyName] = Math.floor((el/featureDivisor)*100); });
      document.querySelector(`#${keyName}Cent`).textContent = quotientTable[keyName].toString() + ' %';
      console.log(sumTable);
      console.log(Object.values(totalSumObj[keyName]));
    } catch(error) { console.error(error) }
  };
```

I expect the arithmetic based on the inputs to be accurate, instead it is not.

`52+52+52+48+48+48` ought to = 300, instead it comes to 298

`Math.floor((12/12)*100)` ought to = 100, instead it comes to 200, or even 66.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

It was that the declarations were out of order such that a number would be displayed *before* calculation rather than after. *And* the quotientTable obj is unnecessary.

**The solution function:**

```
const doCalculation = function(confidenceValue, keyName) {
try {
  sumTable[keyName] = 0;
  totalSumObj[keyName][confidenceValue] = parseInt(document.querySelector(`#${confidenceValue}`).value);
  sumTable[keyName] = Object.values(totalSumObj[keyName]).reduce((a,b)=>a+b, 0);
  let totalSubtotal = Object.values(sumTable).reduce((a, b) => a+b, 0);
  let featureDivisor = parseInt(document.querySelector(`#${keyName}Max`).textContent);

  document.querySelector(`#${keyName}`).textContent = sumTable[keyName].toString();
  document.querySelector(`#${keyName}Cent`).textContent = Math.floor((sumTable[keyName]/featureDivisor)*100).toString() + ' %';
  document.querySelector('#totalPoints').textContent = totalSubtotal.toString();
  document.querySelector('#overallPercent').textContent = Math.floor((totalSubtotal/300)*100).toString() + ' %';
} catch(error) { console.error(error) }
};
```